# Intent and OnActivityResult causing Activity to get restart Actuomatically : Require to solve this issues

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

i am having 20 imageview and i am having 20 button for them when i click any 1 button it gives me option to select image from gallery or camera when i select any option for example galley it will take me to the gallery and let me select image from their and let me display those images on my imageview for respective button 
now the problem is sometimes when i do the whole above process my activity is getting restart actuomatically and all the image which were first selected get vanished from their imageview
For Refernce my code is as follow:

```
    @Override
         public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.new_upload);

      // *****************Assigning Button variable their Id declare in XML
      // file starts here*****************

      new_select1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_select1);
      new_select2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_select2);
      new_select3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_select3);
      new_select4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_select4);
      new_select5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_select5);
      new_select6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_select6);
      new_select7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_select7);
      new_select8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_select8);
      new_select9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_select9);
      new_select10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_select10);
      new_select11 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_select11);
      new_select12 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_select12);
      new_select13 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_select13);
      new_select14 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_select14);
      new_select15 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_select15);
      new_select16 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_select16);
      new_select17 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_select17);
      new_select18 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_select18);
      new_select19 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_select19);
      new_select20 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_select20);


      // *****************Assigning Button variable their Id declare in XML
      // file ends here*****************

      // *****************Assigning Image variable their Id declare in XML
      // file starts here*****************

      new_selectimage1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.new_selectImage1);
      new_selectimage2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.new_selectImage2);
      new_selectimage3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.new_selectImage3);
      new_selectimage4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.new_selectImage4);
      new_selectimage5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.new_selectImage5);
      new_selectimage6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.new_selectImage6);
      new_selectimage7 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.new_selectImage7);
      new_selectimage8 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.new_selectImage8);
      new_selectimage9 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.new_selectImage9);
      new_selectimage10 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.new_selectImage10);
      new_selectimage11 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.new_selectImage11);
      new_selectimage12 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.new_selectImage12);
      new_selectimage13 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.new_selectImage13);
      new_selectimage14 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.new_selectImage14);
      new_selectimage15 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.new_selectImage15);
      new_selectimage16 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.new_selectImage16);
      new_selectimage17 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.new_selectImage17);
      new_selectimage18 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.new_selectImage18);
      new_selectimage19 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.new_selectImage19);
      new_selectimage20 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.new_selectImage20);

      // ****Assigning Image variable their Id declare in XML file ends
      // here*****************


      // **************Creating Dialog to give option to user to new_select
      // image from gallery or from camera starts here****************

      final String[] items = new String[] { "From Camera", "From Gallery" };
      ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, items);
      AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

      builder.setTitle("select Image");
      builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
        if (item == 0) {
         if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState()
           .equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
          Intent intent = new Intent(
            MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
          File file = new File(Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            "/AUSRWC/picture" + ".jpg");
          mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

          try {
           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Click Image",
             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           intent.putExtra(
             android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
             mImageCaptureUri);
           intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
           startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
          } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
          }
         } else {
          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
            "Please insert SdCard First",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
         dialog.cancel();
        } else {
         Intent intent = new Intent();
         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Select Image",
           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         intent.setType("image/*");
         intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

         startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
           "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_FILE);
        }
       }
      });

      dialog = builder.create();
      // **************Creating Dialog to give option to user to new_select
      // image from gallery or from camera ends here****************


      // ********************Image 1 button code starts
      // here*******************************
       new_select1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         buttonpressed = 1;
         dialog.show();
        }
       });

      // ********************Image 1 button code ends
      // here*******************************

      // ********************Image 2 button code starts
      // here*******************************
       new_select2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         buttonpressed = 2;
         dialog.show();
        }
       });

      // ********************Image 2 button code ends
      // here*******************************

      // ********************Image 3 button code starts
      // here*******************************

       new_select3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         buttonpressed = 3;
         dialog.show();
        }
       });


      // ********************Image 3 button code ends
      // here*******************************

      // ********************Image 4 button code starts
      // here*******************************
      new_select4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         buttonpressed = 4;
         dialog.show();
        }
       });

      // ********************Image 4 button code ends
      // here*******************************

      // ********************Image 5 button code starts
      // here*******************************
     new_select5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         buttonpressed = 5;
         dialog.show();
        }
       });

      // ********************Image 5 button code ends
      // here*******************************

      // ********************Image 6 button code starts
      // here*******************************
      new_select6.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         buttonpressed = 6;
         dialog.show();
        }
       });


      // ********************Image 6 button code ends
      // here*******************************

      // ********************Image 7 button code starts
      // here*******************************
     new_select7.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        buttonpressed = 7;
         dialog.show();
        }
       });

      // ********************Image 7 button code ends
      // here*******************************

      // ********************Image 8 button code starts
      // here*******************************
       new_select8.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         buttonpressed = 8;
         dialog.show();
        }
       });

      // ********************Image 8 button code ends
      // here*******************************

      // ********************Image 9 button code starts
      // here*******************************
      new_select9.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        buttonpressed = 9;
         dialog.show();
        }
       });

      // ********************Image 9 button code ends
      // here*******************************

      // ********************Image 10 button code starts
      // here*******************************
       new_select10.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        buttonpressed = 10;
         dialog.show();
        }
       });

      // ********************Image 10 button code ends
      // here*******************************

      // ********************Image 11 button code starts
      // here*******************************
       new_select11.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         buttonpressed = 11;
         dialog.show();
        }
       });

      // ********************Image 11 button code ends
      // here*******************************

      // ********************Image 12 button code starts
      // here*******************************
      new_select12.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         buttonpressed = 12;
         dialog.show();
        }
       });

      // ********************Image 12 button code ends
      // here*******************************

      // ********************Image 13 button code starts
      // here*******************************
      new_select13.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         buttonpressed = 13;
         dialog.show();
        }
       });

      // ********************Image 13 button code ends
      // here*******************************

      // ********************Image 14 button code starts
      // here*******************************
      new_select14.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         buttonpressed = 14;
         dialog.show();
        }
       });

      // ********************Image 14 button code ends
      // here*******************************

      // ********************Image 15 button code starts
      // here*******************************
      new_select15.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         buttonpressed = 15;
         dialog.show();
        }
       });


      // ********************Image 15 button code ends
      // here*******************************

      // ********************Image 16 button code starts
      // here*******************************
      new_select16.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         buttonpressed = 16;
         dialog.show();
        }
       });

      // ********************Image 16 button code ends
      // here*******************************

      // ********************Image 17 button code starts
      // here*******************************
     new_select17.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         buttonpressed = 17;
         dialog.show();
        }
       });


      // ********************Image 17 button code ends
      // here*******************************

      // ********************Image 18 button code starts
      // here*******************************
      new_select18.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         buttonpressed = 18;
         dialog.show();
        }
       });

      // ********************Image 18 button code ends
      // here*******************************

      // ********************Image 19 button code starts
      // here*******************************
      new_select19.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        buttonpressed = 19;
         dialog.show();
        }
       });


      // ********************Image 19 button code ends
      // here*******************************

      // ********************Image 20 button code starts
      // here*******************************
     new_select20.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         buttonpressed = 20;
         dialog.show();
        }
       });

      // ********************Image 20 button code ends
      // here*******************************
    }

   // ***********************To get Path of new_selected Image code starts
     // here************************************

     public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
      String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
      Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);

      if (cursor == null)
       return null;

      int column_index = cursor
        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);

      cursor.moveToFirst();

      return cursor.getString(column_index);
     }

     // ***********************To get Path of new_selected Image code ends
     // here************************************

     // **********************Picture obtained from the camera or from gallery
     // code starts here**************
     @Override
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      //path = "";
      Log.e("","requestCode="+requestCode); 
      switch (requestCode){

       case PICK_FROM_FILE:

                    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                     mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();
                path = getRealPathFromURI(mImageCaptureUri); // from Gallery
                Log.e("", "Imagepath from gallery=" + path);
                if (path == null)
                path = mImageCaptureUri.getPath(); // from File Manager

                if (path != null) {
                dialog1 = ProgressDialog.show(new_upload.this, "",
                  "Processing Please wait...", true);
                new ImageDisplayTask().execute();
               }
                    }
                    break;
       case PICK_FROM_CAMERA:
           if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            try {
             path = mImageCaptureUri.getPath();
             Log.e("", "Imagepath from Camera =" + path);
             // bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
            } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (path != null) {
             dialog1 = ProgressDialog.show(new_upload.this, "",
               "Processing Please wait...", true);
             //new ImageDisplayTask1().execute();
             new ImageDisplayTask().execute();
            }
           }
           break;
                default:

                }
    }

     // ********************Picture obtained from the camera or from gallery code
     // ends here*********************************************

     // ******************Image Display on Button when new_selected from gallery
     // Ashynch Code starts here********************************

     class ImageDisplayTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(Void... unsued) {

       Bitmap src = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
       Bitmap dest = Bitmap.createBitmap(src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(),
         Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

       //Bitmap dest = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(src, src.getWidth(),src.getHeight(), true);
       SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
       String dateTime = sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()); // reading local ``
       String timestamp = dateTime + "    " + roadworthynumber;

       SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
       String dateTime1 = sdf1.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
       Imagename = dateTime1.toString().trim().replaceAll(":", "")
         .replaceAll("-", "").replaceAll(" ", "")
         + roadworthynumber + ".jpg";

       Canvas cs = new Canvas(dest);
       Paint tPaint = new Paint();
       tPaint.setTextSize(100);
       tPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);
       tPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
       tPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
       cs.drawBitmap(src, 0f, 0f, null);
       float height = tPaint.measureText("yY");
       cs.drawText(timestamp, 5f, src.getHeight() - height + 5f, tPaint);
       try {
        dest.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70,
          new FileOutputStream(new File(cacheDir, Imagename)));
        dest.recycle();
        src.recycle();
       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return null;
      }

      @Override
      protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... unsued) {

      }

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String serverresponse) {
      String error = "noerror";
       Display currentDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
       int dw = currentDisplay.getWidth();
       int dh = currentDisplay.getHeight() - 100;
       Log.e("", "width= " + dw + " Height= " + dh);
       try {

        BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(
          Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/AUSRWC/"
            + Imagename, bmpFactoryOptions);
        int heightRatio = (int) Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outHeight
          / (float) dh);
        int widthRatio = (int) Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outWidth
          / (float) dw);
        if (heightRatio > 1 && widthRatio > 1) {
         if (heightRatio > widthRatio) {
          bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = heightRatio;
         } else {
          bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = widthRatio;
         }
        }
        bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(
          Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/AUSRWC/"
            + Imagename, bmpFactoryOptions);

      if (buttonpressed == 1) {
           new_selectimage1.setImageBitmap(bmp); //Image set on ImageView
        } else if (buttonpressed == 2) {
         new_selectimage2.setImageBitmap(bmp);//Image set on ImageView
        } else if (buttonpressed == 3) {
         new_selectimage3.setImageBitmap(bmp);//Image set on ImageView
        } else if (buttonpressed == 4) {
         new_selectimage4.setImageBitmap(bmp);//Image set on ImageView
        } else if (buttonpressed == 5) {
         new_selectimage5.setImageBitmap(bmp);//Image set on ImageView
        } else if (buttonpressed == 6) {
         new_selectimage6.setImageBitmap(bmp);//Image set on ImageView
        } else if (buttonpressed == 7) {
         new_selectimage7.setImageBitmap(bmp);//Image set on ImageView
        } else if (buttonpressed == 8) {
         new_selectimage8.setImageBitmap(bmp);//Image set on ImageView
        } else if (buttonpressed == 9) {
         new_selectimage9.setImageBitmap(bmp);//Image set on ImageView
       } else if (buttonpressed == 10) {
         new_selectimage10.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        } else if (buttonpressed == 11) {
         new_selectimage11.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        } else if (buttonpressed == 12) {
         new_selectimage12.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        } else if (buttonpressed == 13) {
          new_selectimage13.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    } else if (buttonpressed == 14) {
     new_selectimage14.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    } else if (buttonpressed == 15) {
     new_selectimage15.setImageBitmap(bmp);
     } else if (buttonpressed == 16) {
     new_selectimage16.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    } else if (buttonpressed == 17) {
     new_selectimage17.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    } else if (buttonpressed == 18) {
     new_selectimage18.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    } else if (buttonpressed == 19) {
     new_selectimage19.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    } else if (buttonpressed == 20) {
     new_selectimage20.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }
       } catch (Exception e)
    {
       Log.e("",e.tostring());
    }
```

My Log IS as follow

```
06-11 12:36:43.899: I/ActivityManager(163): Process com.AUSRWC (pid 18012) has died.
06-11 12:36:43.899: I/ActivityManager(163): Low Memory: No more background processes.
06-11 12:36:43.909: I/WindowManager(163): WIN DEATH: Window{409be3d0 com.AUSRWC/com.AUSRWC.new_upload paused=false}
06-11 12:36:45.199: I/InputReader(163): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 0
06-11 12:36:45.199: I/InputDispatcher(163): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0, channel '40866bd8 com.cooliris.media/com.cooliris.media.Gallery (server)'
06-11 12:36:45.279: I/InputReader(163): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 1
06-11 12:36:45.279: I/InputDispatcher(163): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 1, channel '40866bd8 com.cooliris.media/com.cooliris.media.Gallery (server)'
06-11 12:36:45.279: D/Gallery(18750): performReturn : contentUri = content://media/external/images/media/421
06-11 12:36:45.289: D/Gallery(18750): performReturn : result = Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/421 }
06-11 12:36:45.289: I/RenderView(18750): OnPause RenderView com.cooliris.media.RenderView@40515188
06-11 12:36:45.289: E/SensorManager(18750): unregisterListener:: all sensors,  listener = com.cooliris.media.RenderView@40515188
06-11 12:36:45.299: I/GLThread(18750): onPause tid=46
06-11 12:36:45.299: I/Main thread(18750): onPause waiting for mPaused.
06-11 12:36:45.299: I/Main thread(18750): onPause waiting for mPaused.
06-11 12:36:45.309: I/GLThread(18750): mPaused is now true tid=46
06-11 12:36:45.309: I/GLThread(18750): releasing EGL surface because paused tid=46
06-11 12:36:45.309: W/EglHelper(18750): destroySurface()  tid=46
06-11 12:36:45.319: W/EglHelper(18750): finish() tid=46
06-11 12:36:45.349: I/GLThread(18750): releasing EGL context because paused tid=46
06-11 12:36:45.359: I/ActivityManager(163): Start proc com.AUSRWC for activity com.AUSRWC/.new_upload: pid=18810 uid=10067 gids={3003, 1006, 1015}
06-11 12:36:45.419: I/OrientationDebug(163): [pwm] in updateOrientationListenerLp()
06-11 12:36:45.419: V/OrientationDebug(163): in updateOrientationListenerLp(), Screen status=true, current orientation=1, SensorEnabled=true
06-11 12:36:45.419: I/OrientationDebug(163): [pwm] needSensorRunningLp(), return true #4
06-11 12:36:45.439: E/jdwp(18810): Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
06-11 12:36:45.499: I/GLThread(18750): noticed surfaceView surface lost tid=46
06-11 12:36:45.609: I/ApplicationPackageManager(18810): cscCountry is not German : INU
```

Comment: please cleanup your code, difficult to make sense of it as it is now.

Comment: @Orlmyee Thanks for your response....
I had edited the code as per your requirement.So now please go through my code and can you please let me know why i am getting the error...Also will like to add few more details which i had founded out while doing testing more on it.

Comment: 1)The problem does not occur when i am testing on emulator it occurs when i am trying to select images in my android phone version 2.3.4 Device name Samsung galaxy ace 2) The problem mostly occurs when I have already selected 15 images from my gallery and I try to select images afterwards. 3)Also since i am using my device i am not getting proper log for the same @doesn't come to know why such error is occuring.I had tried to use Log at all point but no use.Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be due to memory utilization. Try testing the code using Memory Analyzer Tool so that you can identify the problem.

If you post the log statements during the time when the activity re-creates, i can help u better.

Comment: Also post your xml file so that we can try testing at our end

Comment: hi user623517
can you please tell me how can i send my all files to you since in stack they don't allow to post bigger code and also the code which i had posted is cut short due to this limitataion.

Comment: One more thing will like to add up over here is after going through everything i found out few thing as below.
1)The problem does not occur when i am testing on emulator it occurs when i am trying to select images in my android phone version 2.3.4 Device name Samsung galaxy ace
2) The problem mostly occurs when I have already selected 15 images from my gallery and I try to select images afterwards.
3)Also since i am using my device i am not getting proper log for the same @doesn't come to know why such error is occuring.I had tried to use Log at all point but no use.Please help

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the activity is being recreated.
try adding the following to your activity entry in the manifest

`android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:launchMode="singleTask"`

Comment: Can you post the log output when you run it on the device? i take it that changing launchMode did not help? post the log output.

Comment: According to your need i had added my Log which i am getting when i run my application and get the error into my mobile